# Using regex, match a string and then pull integer value out of match

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to:

1. match the given input if it has the `[ process id N ]` where N can be any integer value (actually positive value).
2. return the N integer value from the match.

The following seems to work in a two phase call but is there (should be) a way to both match the string and pull the integer out in one call to the Regex?

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication25
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string instanceName = "message read rate [ process id 1776 ]";

            Regex expression = new Regex(@".*process id (\d).*");
            var matches = expression.Match(instanceName);

            string processId = Regex.Match(matches.Value, @"\d+").Value;

            Console.WriteLine(processId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `new Regex(@".*process id (\d+).*")` and then `myMatch.Groups[1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you care about performance and your input string is large, you will want to drop the `.*` that you have used in your regex at the beginning and end, because they really serve no purpose whatsoever.

Secondly, you certainly can use `(\d+)` in your first regex to get all the numbers within the process ID instead of a single number with `(\d)` (as several have already mentioned). You can then access it through `matches.Groups[1].Value`.

Last, it is safer if you use `if (matches.Success)`, just so you don't get errors when there is no match:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication25
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string instanceName = "message read rate [ process id 1776 ]";

            Regex expression = new Regex(@"process id (\d+)");
            var matches = expression.Match(instanceName);

            if (matches.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Process ID: " + matches.Groups[1].Value);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No match found");
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

As to why removing `.*` makes the regex less efficient, you might want to read on greedy quantifiers and backtracking. In simple terms, `.*` will match everything till the end of the string (except newlines, unless the DOTALL flag is active, where it'll be able to match even more and reduce efficiency even more) and then will go back one character at a time to get the other matches in the regex. The more characters in the string, the slower it becomes since there's more to backtrack.

The `.Match` function doesn't need to match the whole string; it will find a match anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
var match = expression.Match(instanceName);
var processId = Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
    string instanceName = "message read rate [ process id 1776 ]";
    var s = Regex.Match(instanceName, @".*process id (\d+).*");
    Console.WriteLine(s.Groups[1]);
```

Instead of this:

```
string instanceName = "message read rate [ process id 1776 ]";

            Regex expression = new Regex(@".*process id (\d).*");
            var matches = expression.Match(instanceName);

            string processId = Regex.Match(matches.Value, @"\d+").Value;

            Console.WriteLine(processId);
```

Comment: and where's the difference to the original post, except introducing another regexing instead of using groups properly?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Whats the meaning of _using groups properly ?_ do you mean to say 2+2=4 is correct and 2*2 is not using maths properly ? There's no need to create that `expression`, which itself is a positive in terms of performance

Comment: ahh ... sorry ... I did not see the "instead of this" ... haha ... :) take this as an apology!

Answer (score 2):

While the answers about using Groups are correct, I prefer to use Named Groups.  For your example, it may be overkill, but when you start to use more complex regex's, it is easier to keep track of what the various groups are:

```
    string instanceName = "message read rate [ process id 1776 ]";
    string expression = @".*process id (?<PROCESS_ID>\d+).*";

    Match match = Regex.Match(instanceName, expression);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        string processId = match.Groups["PROCESS_ID"].Value.Trim();
        Console.WriteLine("Process ID is {0}", processId);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Could not find process id");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to this

```
(?<=process id )\d+
```

This will match the id number only

Answer (score 0):

No. Regex is made for searching texts and parsing numerics is meant to be done by yourself.

To the downvoter: the question was not how to extract a number using regex, but how to extract the number as an integer straight by regex engine, which is unrealizable.

Comment: _The following seems to work in a two phase call but is there (should be) a way to both match the string and pull the integer out in one call to the Regex?_ OP has clearly mentioned about using c# call. Then how the hell does, _extracting a number from regex engine_ is valid in this context. I also know that after getting my comment, you'll downvote me, but I don't care, bcuz i've done what is right according to me

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair check out my elaboration